# Why Amazon S3 signed URL works locally but not on production server?

Tags: python, django, boto

I would like to know what causes this signed URL method to work locally but not in the real server?

Locally it produces a URL that expires in 12 s, but in the server it returns a expired URL?

```
def s3_signed_url(file_path):
    import boto
    s3conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = s3conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME, validate=False)
    key = bucket.new_key(file_path)
    signed_url = key.generate_url(expires_in=12)
    return signed_url



@never_cache
def enjoy_the_show(request, movie_id):
    m = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk=movie_id)
    iOS = is_ios_device(request)
    if (iOS is True):
        movie_path = m.m3u8_url
        movie_path = movie_path.replace('https://s3.amazonaws.com/domain.com','')
        signed_url = s3_signed_url(movie_path)
        return render_to_response('movies/enjoy_show_iOS.html', {'signed_url':signed_url,'movie': m,'is_logged_in':is_logged_in(request)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('movies/enjoy_show.html', {'movie': m,'is_logged_in':is_logged_in(request)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue was related with the timezone and server clock

Comment: +1 for mentioning boto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved. It was a timezone issue.
The issue can be fixed by configuring the timezone properly on both servers, and / or having into consideration the time difference.